# MS SQL Express 2012 slow in VirtualBox image

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2012, virtualbox, ehcache

I am accessing MS SQL Server Express running in a VirtualBox image for a Java / Hibernate (with EhCache setup) application.

The VM is connected via NIC mode.

When the server starts up it loads (most of the DB's) data in EhCache.

Right now it takes ~5 minutes to start up. If I switch to a dedicated machine that hosts MS SQL Server (not Express) the startup takes ~1 min.

Any suggestions what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem.

VirtualBox in NIC mode somehow reduces the network speed between host and guest to 10mps.

More can be found in [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21334) forum thread on the Virtualbox site.

For a ticket in this regard (that seems to be marke as fixed but isn't, at least not in version 4.3.10 r93012) see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/757)